# Does FreeAndNil procedure also free TStringList created in thread?

Tags: delphi

```
for x:=0 to NumberOfWaitingThreads-1 do
begin

  WaitForThread:=TWaitForThread.Create(true);
  ArrayOfHandles[x]:=WaitForThread.Handle;
  WaitForThread.FreeOnTerminate:=false;
  WaitForThread.CommandLineList:=TStringList.Create; 
  WaitForThread.CommandLineList.Text:=CommandList.Text;
  WaitForThread.Resume;

end;

CommandList.Free;

repeat
  WaitStatus:=WaitForMultipleObjects(NumberOfWaitingThreads,@ArrayOfHandles[0], True, 100);
until WaitStatus<>WAIT_TIMEOUT;

FreeAndNil(WaitForThread);
```

Does **FreeAndNil(WaitForThread)** also free TStringList created here **WaitForThread.CommandLineList:=TStringList.Create;**

Comment: No, you will have to do that in a thread destructor.

Comment: This issue would be easier if you just had a class derived from TObject. Then you could see the basic principles without having the extraneous detail obscuring things.

Comment: Looking at the threading, the wait looks expensive. Why do you loop at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does `FreeAndNil(WaitForThread)` also free `TStringList` created here `WaitForThread.CommandLineList:=TStringList.Create;`

`FreeAndNil(WaitForThread)` will only free the thread itself, not any objects created by the thread.

So, the answer is no, you will have to do that in the thread destructor.

---

Note that if `NumberOfWaitingThreads` > 1, you will leak all thread objects but the last one. Fix that by declaring an array of `TWaitForThread`:

```
var
  WaitForThreadArr : array of TWaitForThread;
...

SetLength(WaitForThreadArr,NumberOfWaitingThreads);
for x := 0 to NumberOfWaitingThreads-1 do
begin

  WaitForThreadArr[x] := TWaitForThread.Create(true);
  ArrayOfHandles[x] := WaitForThreadArr[x].Handle;
  WaitForThreadArr[x].FreeOnTerminate := false;
  WaitForThreadArr[x].CommandLineList := TStringList.Create; 
  WaitForThreadArr[x].CommandLineList.Text := CommandList.Text;
  WaitForThreadArr[x].Start;
end;

CommandList.Free;

repeat
  WaitStatus := WaitForMultipleObjects(NumberOfWaitingThreads,@ArrayOfHandles[0], True, 100);
until WaitStatus <> WAIT_TIMEOUT;

for x := 0 to NumberOfWaitingThreads - 1 do begin
  Free(WaitForThreadArr[x]);
end;
```

Comment: The answer is maybe.  `FreeAndNil` will call the destructor.  We don't know what the destructor does.

Comment: @J..., the question would be unfounded if that was the case.

Comment: Is this sufficient or it has to be done via destructor? 
FreeAndNil(WaitForThread.CommandLineList);
FreeAndNil(WaitForThread);

Comment: It will work, but would break the principles of ownership. I would strongly advice not to.

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera We don't know.  If `CommandLineList` is a property it won't work.  If it's a public field it will, but if that's the case then you're doing this entirely wrong.  The class should manage its own assets, the consumer likewise.

Comment: @LU RD
Ok. Thank you. I will do it via destructor then.

Comment: If you are freeing `WaitForThread` anyway, why would you use `FreeAndNil` on the string list at all? The `WaitForThread` will be gone anyway, so there is no need to set the string list to nil: its owner will be gone directly after. Just do `CommandLineList.Free;` in the destructor of the thread. Do not free it from outside. That is bad practice. And don't use `FreeAndNil` for that.

Comment: If `NumberOfWaitingThreads` is > 1, this code is leaking all thread objects other than the last one created, so it won't matter if the thread destructor frees the `TStringList` as the destructor is not being called for all of the threads other than the last one. To fix that, store all of the thread objects in an array/list, and then loop through that array/list once all of the threads have terminated.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau
Could you post an example code? This would greatly help me to understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: What Remy means, is that you assign the same `WaitForThread` variable to `NumberOfWaitingThreads` instances. That will overwrite all objects, but the last one, hence the leaks. Declare an array of thread objects (i.e. WaitForThreadArr : array of TThread) and allocate: SetLength(WaiForThreadArr,NumberOfWaitingThreads) before the loop.

Comment: Can I replace Free(WaitForThreadArr[x]); with FreeAndNil(WaitForThreadArr[x]) ?

Comment: Yes you can. Normally FreeAndNil is "needed" only for reuse of the variables, but I tend to avoid those situations. By needed, I mean so it can be tested with Assigned. And I avoid it because it is very easy to mess up code that way.

Comment: Yes I need FreeAndNill for Assigned function ,that's why I ask. 
Last question and I will shut up. Does your modified code still require freeing TStringList in destructor?

Comment: Yes, that is required :-)

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera: You seem to have problems uznderstanding ownership and why you didn't free any but the last thread. I advise you to read a good book about Delphi memory management, e.g. [the one by Dalija Prasnikar](https://dalija.prasnikar.info/delphimm/) (no affiliation, except that I bought it too).